# Python - Create a nested join query using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Any ideas for how I could do a nested join using SQLAlchemy? Here is the raw query I am trying to recreate.

```
SELECT "tblLinkDivisions"."DivisionCoLinkID", 5 AS Score, "tblCompanies"."CompanyID"
FROM "tblS_AppliedStrategy"
INNER JOIN
(
  (
      "tblLinkIndustry" INNER JOIN "tblLinkDivisions" ON "tblLinkIndustry"."IndustryCoLinkID" = "tblLinkDivisions"."IndustryCoLinkID"
  )
  INNER JOIN "tblLinkAppliedStrategy"
  ON "tblLinkDivisions"."DivisionCoLinkID" = "tblLinkAppliedStrategy"."DivisionCoLinkID"
)
ON "tblS_AppliedStrategy"."AppStrategyCode" = "tblLinkAppliedStrategy"."AppStrategyCode"
INNER JOIN "tblCompanies" ON ("tblCompanies"."CompanyID" = "tblLinkIndustry"."CompanyID" AND "tblCompanies"."CompanyID" != %s)
WHERE "tblS_AppliedStrategy"."AppStrategyCode" IN %s
```

I have tried a few different solutions with this being the closest outcome:

```
    companies = (
        session.query(tblLinkDivisions.DivisionCoLinkID, tblCompanies.CompanyID)
        .select_from(tblS_AppliedStrategy)
        .join(tblLinkIndustry, tblLinkDivisions.IndustryCoLinkID == tblLinkIndustry.IndustryCoLinkID)
        .join(tblLinkAppliedStrategy, tblLinkDivisions.DivisionCoLinkID == tblLinkAppliedStrategy.DivisionCoLinkID)
        .join(tblLinkAppliedStrategy, tblS_AppliedStrategy.AppStrategyCode == tblLinkAppliedStrategy.AppStrategyCode)
        .join(tblCompanies, and_(tblCompanies.CompanyID == tblLinkIndustry.CompanyID, tblCompanies.CompanyID != company_id))
        .filter(tblS_AppliedStrategy.AppStrategyCode.in_(strategy))
        .all()
    )
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!